# How many users registered on this site?

Tags: support, users

How many users are registered on Stack Overflow?

Comment: See: http://stackexchange.com/sites, where you would find 5.2m

Comment: Cross-site duplicates: [How many users does Stack Overflow actually have?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109573) and [How many users are there on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65256)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Wow! Currently is 11m, which is a huge increase over 3 years!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hovering over the user count on Stack Overflow's row [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday), you see this:

> 10,043,767 registered and unregistered users

Which is probably the number you want.

Comment: Click the logo/image to see rounded figures, then hover to see exact details. Btw, now shows 8.5m users.