# Underline in [`code`](links)

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-review, design, markdown-rendering

Apparently [links are now underlined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314275/underline-appearing-for-hyperlinks). While I'm personally not a big fan of this, this seems to be a design decision.

However, code in links is underlined as well. This makes it rather hard to read.

> Use [`this command`](https://stackoverflow.com/) or use [`this_command`](https://stackoverflow.com/)

```
Use [`this command`](https://stackoverflow.com/) or 
use [`this_command`](https://stackoverflow.com/)
```

Can at least links that contain code not be underlined please.

Note: There is [Inline tags (inserted by [tag:] markup) are now underlined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372693/inline-tags-inserted-by-tag-markup-are-now-underlined) but I don't know if the answer applies only to tags or also to `code`.

Comment: Also, it looks like, along with this change, links have also been recolored, so they're standard-link-blue when unvisited, but a bluish/slate grey when visited. Which looks great in plain text, where a brighter color for a link you've already seen might be distracting (especially when you already have the underline to signal the same thing). But in a code tag, that's just grey on slightly darker grey.

Comment: Why is this so hard to userstyle? Apparently setting `text-decoration:none` on several variations of `a>code` doesnt work

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372719/underlines-everywhere-should-be-probably-removed-from-the-stack-snippet#comment622282_372719

Comment: @astonearachnid: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693866/how-to-remove-css-line-through/13693884#13693884 (and [a number of my other answers on text decorations](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+propagate+decorations))

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks - `display:inline-block` works and doesn't mess up the positioning.

Comment: Also mixed code/not code links look terrible (like two separate links), as I mention [on the MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314391/397084)

Comment: Here's another awful looking example that I just stumbled upon: [Regex pattern](https://s8.postimg.cc/dhiyk8zfp/regex.png).

Comment: I'm curious why 6 people (so far) have downvoted this? Do they disagree that code links shouldn't be underlined?

Comment: @DavidG Five people have upvoted kjhughes' answer supporting the underlining. I, for one, think it would have been an improvement weren't it for the issue with underscores.

Comment: Here's a tag for you: [tag:bug]. It does not look like a [tag]

Comment: Can we get rid of this (design decision)?! I like the way it was :)

Comment: Perhaps SO could [set a `border-bottom` instead](https://jsfiddle.net/rk2450py/4/)?

Comment: I added this rule to stylebot `.post-text a:not(.post-tag), .comment-copy a, .wmd-preview a:not(.post-tag) {
    text-decoration: none;
}
` just as when they added that side border, and the design change I don't like vanishes.

Answer (score 135):

It's not just a matter of being hard to read; this is actually hiding information, in a way that's going to confuse novices.

You could argue that nobody's going to be stupid enough to think that C++ has a type called [`unordered set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered%20set/unordered%20set/) instead of [`unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/)—well, you *could* argue that, if you could see the difference.

But what happens when I tell someone to use `ls -a` to see if there's a [`.DS_Store`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) file, and they report that they couldn't find anything named `.DS Store`, even after putting quotes around it?

---

Sure, we could change the way we write our answers. Instead of this:

> You want to use the [`new_child`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap.new_child) method, instead of calling the constructor, like this:

… I could write:

> You want to use the `new_child` method ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap.new_child)), instead of calling the constructor, like this:

But that's more verbose, and there's no counterbalancing improvement.

Not to mention that, even if we did all change overnight, that wouldn't affect the zillions of answers already on the site.

Comment: It does seem like a poorly thought out design decision especially since it was made in the name of accessibility. I'm surprised it wasn't tested much more thoroughly.

Comment: C++ has a type called `unsigned long long int`, so it wouldn't be to stupid to believe that it has a type called `unordered set`.

Comment: Is it my imagination, or has a change been made very recently to make the underscore character (just barely) visible even when underlined? If I look closely, I can now tell which underlined terms in this post include underscores, I don't think I could do that earlier.

Comment: @Blackwood It's not your imagination. As far as I can tell, underscores within links within code within quotes can be seen more or less clearly.

Comment: @duplode I wouldn't say "more or less clearly". If you look very carefully, you can now see the line is a pixel thicker in the space in [`unordered_set`](http://example.com) but not in [`unordered set`](http://example.com), but that's hardly something you can expect most people to pick up on.

Comment: Note that @duplode refers to underscores within links within quotes. I you look at your two blockquotes with "new_child" the underscore is not the same colour as the underline, which helps the contrast a little bit. I agree that the difference may be too slight.

Comment: @Blackwood Ah, you're right, it's a pixel thicker _and also darker_. Which I didn't notice when zooming in to see the difference, but did notice when zooming in to see the difference after being told to look for another difference. Maybe this just means I've been wearing my contacts too long (I tend to forget to take out my extended-wear disposables until a few days after I'm supposed to…), but I think it demonstrates that (a) the devs are right that the color scheme they've chosen doesn't allow for sufficient contrast, and (b) they're wrong that underlines are the solution to that problem.

Comment: @abarnert Yup. Every time I post a link within code I wonder if people will notice the difference between blue on grey and black on grey. Underlining would be a neat solution for that -- shame about the underscores.

Comment: You are right, this breaks code in links all over the site. This is horrible, SO needs to do an immediate rollback!

Comment: @BoltClock Ever since Jin left I don't think they've really had a cohesive design strategy.

Comment: What if SO used dotted underlines? It's still not super readable, but it's better than solid underlines

Comment: @Blackwood even worse, you can tell the difference only if the underline is present (or you have both variants next to each other like in this answer or just have remembered the existence of this difference and hope, that no other design change happened since then). In all other cases, someone seeing, e.g. [`unordered set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered%20set/unordered%20set/) does not know that there is no underline until someone tells them, that the underline would look different.

Answer (score 62):

It's just a matter of taste, but the underlined links look *horrible*. It is horribly distracting to glance at a paragraph and automatically have your eyes drawn to the colored and underlined text. That is a "human factor" to consider. It makes paragraphs awkward to read. For example:

[image]

The code formatting at the beginning of the paragraph is completely obscured (or overpowered) by the link underline.

So much so that in every browser or text editor I generally limit link underline to "underline on hover" to prevent the distraction unless I am explicitly focused on the link. There is a css property that does just that -- that should be employed if you persist with the underlining. Even then, there is no real need for underlying at all in questions or answers, The blue text is more than sufficient for 99.9% of the seeing public. For those that are visually impaired or color-blind, then having the "underline-on-hover" provides a simple way to disclose the existence of a link by moving the mouse over the paragraph without distracting the remaining 99.9% of the color-seeing population.

Underline is a holdover from the days of black-and-white text without italics capability. It was reserved for separating Author and Title information in a citation within a bibliography or end-note. It should generally be avoided mid-page.

I'm all for progress and making the pages more readable for all, but the use of a persistent underline does more harm than good, especially when an underline-on-hover would suffice.

Comment: I agree this looks horrible on SO (thought not as much on some other SE sites), but I think this answer belongs on [the MSE question about underlining in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314275/underline-appearing-for-hyperlinks), not on this question about whether they can exempt links in code from underlining.

Comment: Yes, I thought about a separate question, but if I had done that, there would have been a pile on group dowvote for missing the duplicate and not posting here. I just answered a couple of questions on SO and it really changes the entire intent and readability of a technical answer to have your eyes skip over the first part of a paragraph and straight to the link (which may be for informational or reference purposes only and not a primary part of the paragraph).

Comment: I'm not suggesting you add a separate question; I'm pointing you to a question that already exists, where I think this answer should be added.

Comment: Ah, thank you, yes, there are good suggestions there on readability with underline and it would seem to suggest against the underline in the middle of the paragraph on SO questions/answers.

Comment: So, I'm guessing you missed the link in my comment because, even with the underline, it's hard to spot links that are colored only a slightly different grey from the surrounding text? That might also be worth mentioning…

Comment: No, I got that and I agree with you on the shades of gray. It is just bewildering that for at least the past 4 years the prior link formatting worked just fine, and now we have seem to have come up with a new solution for a non-existent problem. I'd trade the boxed fly-out tags in a heartbeat if I could get the hover-over question title summary back...

Comment: According to the SE devs on that MSE link, this is because of the upcoming major retheming: most of their new themes apparently have even _less_ opportunity for contrast than the current ones, so it will no longer a non-existent problem, so that's why they've solved it with underlining. (Presumably those themes have to be so low-contrast for reasons I don't understand because I'm a code nerd rather than a font nerd. And hey, maybe in the new themes the underlined links won't look terrible, so I'll reserve judgment… but I'm not holding my breath.)

Comment: Amen. The older I get the more stuck in my ways and resistant to change I become. (especially when, like with SO, the format and layout and been so very good for quite some time (banner changes, notwithstanding). If it's not broke, don't fix it `:)` I'll likewise reserve judgment, I just wish they wouldn't piecemeal the stuff. It really is a shock to answer a question and have it look awkward and think "Did I screw something up?" -- no somebody else changed something out of my control. With as large as SE has become, even small changes effect a great number of people.

Comment: "In order to know if you are using a C11 compiler, check [`__STDC_VERSION__`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8)." Gaaah!

Comment: When I added the link to the preprocessor check, there paragraph disappeared... it was nothing but blue-underlined text leaping off the page. Without that reference, the user at least had a fighting chance of finding the actual explanation within the sea-of-blue.... `:)`

Comment: Devil's Advocate: The "color-seeing population" is more like 95% of the population, which is about 350,000,000 worldwide or 458,506 [just on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317837/how-many-users-registered-on-this-site). Are you also suggesting that anyone who can't differentiate color well should be constantly running their mouse across text on the off-chance that an underline pops up on hover? That information should always be available. Users shouldn't have to search for it.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe I won't speak for David, but I'm suggesting that it should work the same way as Wikipedia and countless other sites which have all found _better_ ways to enable accessibility for the other 5%, while at the same time not harming usability for the 95%. Not to mention _also_ working for, e.g, people who can't use a mouse/trackpad/touchscreen and have to tab through links. (And a big part of this is designing for accessibility from the start, rather than trying to bolt it on. Any reason that starts with "We designed some new themes and links aren't visible in them" is not a reason…

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe "*Are you also suggesting that anyone who can't differentiate color well should be constantly running their mouse across text on the off-chance that an underline pops up on hover?*" No. There is no need for that. If they are interested in whether a link is present, then, of course, a simple mouse-over would be all that is required. Paragraphs would still look like paragraphs instead of an awkward flowchart or "Fall Down" game. I appreciate the devils advocate position. It boils down to whether 435,580 should have awkward paragraphs, or 22,925 could mouse-over.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe For example: Most of the color-blind 5% are not color-blind in a way that prevents them from distinguishing bright-blue-on-white vs. black-on-white, so they don't have a problem in the first place. And most of those who _are_, are so limited that they need to use assistive devices anyway, so the site is designed to work with them. What about the small number in the middle? Well, if you log in, you can select a style designed for color-blind users, or you can just turn on underlines. What if you're in that tiny minority and refuse to log in? Then I guess you have to hover links.