# Code links not distinguished on iPhone

Tags: bug, code-formatting, hyperlinks, mobile-web

Links within inline code (backticks) are not rendered in blue nor distinguished any other way from regular text on iPhone (tested on iPhone SE 2020, iOS 14.0.1).

Below is a screenshot for this post:
[How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to the latest git describe command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64393407/850848#64393704)

[image]

Comment: This is a problem with the 'mobile' version of Stack Overflow. You can reproduce/fix it by switching between the mobile and responsive sites (clicking "Mobile" and "Full site" in the footer of each page respectively). I reproduced your bug on the mobile site (Chrome/Android) - the responsive site was fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeVoP.png. Note that the mobile pages aren't really being maintained - you should probably use the responsive site unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Not just a problem of the mobile version. I opened the question with Edge and Firefox on my Windows 10 machine. The only visible distiction is that the links are underlined. Since I usually configered Firefox not to underline links there wouldn't be a distinction either. @WaiHaLee

Comment: The Stacks design for links-in-code is a simple underline under the text. That's what you'll get if you use the responsive site. In fact, the presence of the underline was [decried as horrible by some when it first appeared](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372750/215552). Can't please everyone. It's [status-by-design].

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of this MSE question: [Unable to differentiate between code and hyperlinks with code formatting on mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353718/289905).